# Was Croix and his party the only ones to enter Frelia's Binary Field?

Tags: ar-tonelico

In *Ar Tonelico 2: Melody of Metafalica* in the final episode of Frelia Binary Field when Miwa and Miora face off it appears Miora calls Miwa Mir

> Miora: Hey! Mir! That's not fair! you didn't convert this story again, did you?
>
> Miwa: Hehehe... Who knows.
>
> Miwa: Talking Trash, I found some nostalgic data. why don't i input it into my system?
>
> Miora: what are you up to!?
>
> Miwa: Hehehe... you'll cry out og nostalgia, too. Now, let's go

At this point the background becomes that of Shadow Mir. the final boss or *Ar Tonelico: Melody of Elemia* and Miora seems to recognize it.

it almost seems to me that Miora, who has the same image as that of Shurelia when Mir connected to Shurelia's tower with Raki, became Shurelia as she seems to be referencing what Mir did her Binary field in the first game when Lyner dove into her.

However when Mir suggested that they enter Frelia's Binary Field she said that only 4 would be diving into her, that would be Croix, Mir, Luca and Cloche.

So i am wondering, is Shurelia, Misha and Aurica diving into Frelia as well? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't Diving into Frelia: Shurelia has free access to the Binary Field due to being the Tower Administrator, so she was merely playing along with Mir's game. But as for Aurica and Misha, they aren't actually there: what you saw there are replicas of them created from data copied from the Beta-6D SH Server where their Cosmosphere are located (according to the Garden of the Goddesses Visual Book).

Also, their proper names are Miu and Leila (the latter being another reference to AT1's Binary Field), so NISA failed once again with the names.

Comment: is Miu and Leila supposed to be the names Shurelia and Mir went in the Binary Field?

Comment: Yes, and Miu is frequently used as her name in all out-of-game material where she is in the Binary Field, and she even used it as her alias when she invaded Aurica's and Misha's Cosmospheres in the Flash Cosmosphere games Gust put out sometime ago.

As for Leila, while the proper way of writing it would be "Reira", that's how her Binary Field name was written in AT1.